# Overloading LINQ's Add method for validation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, overloading

I have an `Email` object and am attempting to validate the number of attachments that are in its `List<Attachment>` property.

The trick is that we consume the `Send()` method across a WCF service.  It's easy to validate it server side, but I want to validate it client side first.

I have generated a library that others are supposed to use in order to consume the service, which in turn has a proxy containing all the objects and available methods.  I think I should be able to overload the `Add()` method on the GenericList with some custom code so the collection is checked when anything is added, and if it exceeds the specified maximum then an exception is thrown.

```
public partial class List<Attachment>
{
    public void Add(Attachment item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        if (this.Count() > maxAttachments)
        {
            throw new Exception("fail")
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work - I can't class base.Add() and I can't define partial class with a specified type.

How do I create an overload for the Add method so that I can include some custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own the `Email` class, your best option would be to change the underlying type of the List member to a specialized implementation of a list.

```
public class Email
{
    const int MaxAttachments = /* ... */;

    public Email(/* ... */)
    {
        this.Attachments = new FixedSizeList<Attachment>(MaxAttachments);
    }

    // ...

    public IList<Attachment> Attachments
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

class FixedSizeList<T> : IList<T>
{
    List<T> innerList;
    int maxCount;

    public FixedSizeList(int maxCount)
    {
        this.innerList = new List<T>(maxCount);
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    // override all the IList<T> members here by delegating
    // to your innerList ...
    // ...

    public void Add(T item)
    {
         if (this.Count == this.maxSize)
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException("No more items can be added.");
         }

         this.innerList.Add(item);
    }

    // ...
    // ...
}
```

It's kind of a lot of boilerplate code, but that's really the only way to cleanly override the behavior.

However, if you **don't** own the `Email` class, you can't really do this through traditional means; you'd need a reflection hack to replace the underlying member or something like the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  This will be a headache to implement amongst all the svcutil generated code in my proxy but will definitely work.

Comment: If you are using svcutil.exe, check out the /collectionType (/ct) option; that might ease a bit of the pain.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is not a partial class, so you can't extend it using your own partial classes.

Also, LINQ to Objects does not provide `Add()` on `List<T>`, that's part of the `IList<T>` interface implemented by `List<T>`, and `Add()` is not a virtual or abstract method in `List<T>`, so you can't override it.

What you should look at is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` - this component provides a list implementation similar to `List<T>` with the added capacity to override protected methods that give you a place to do validation tasks.

You don't have to implement the list from scratch, you just inherit from it, and override methods such as `InsertItem()` and `RemoveItem()` to implement custom rules:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class EmailCollection : Collection<Email>
{
    public int MaximumAttachments { get; set; }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Email item)
    {
        if (Count == MaximumAttachments)
        {
            ... throw error
        }

        // do actual insert
        base.InsertItem(index, item)
    }
}
```

`Add()` calls `InsertItem()` under the hood.

Comment: Agree that `Collection<T>` is a much simpler implementation for this (compared to implementing `IList<T>`); of course, it gets tricky if the external library *demands* a `List<T>` - you might need to expose the inner-list somewhere (and explicitly ensure that it *is* a `List<T>` in the ctor, otherwise it is an implementation detail that `List<T>` is the default).